# rake jobs:work not works with classes inheriting from Spree::Base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree, delayed-job

I have added following gems in Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '~> 4.2.7.1'
gem 'spree_core', '3.1.1'
gem 'spree_api', '3.1.1'
gem 'spree_backend', '3.1.1'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', '~> 3.1.0'

gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
```

I have one class:

```
module Spree
  class EntityAttribute < Spree::Base
      validates_length_of :entity, :maximum => 100
      ...
      ...
 end
end
```

With this code, when I run `bundle exec rake jobs:work`, I get following error:

> [Worker(host:My.local pid:4654)] Starting job worker
>
> rake aborted! TypeError: superclass mismatch for class EntityAttribute
>   /Users/saurabh.mimani/work/codes/local/local_web_backend/app/models/spree/entity_attribute.rb:2:in
>   `<module:Spree>'
>   /Users/saurabh.mimani/work/codes/local/local_web_backend/app/models/spree/entity_attribute.rb:1:in`
>   '
>   /Users/saurabh.mimani/work/codes/local/local_web_backend/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in
>   `load'
>   /Users/saurabh.mimani/work/codes/local/local_web_backend/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in`
>   block in load'
>   /Users/saurabh.mimani/work/codes/local/local_web_backend/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in
>   `load_dependency'
>   /Users/saurabh.mimani/work/codes/local/local_web_backend/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in`
>   load'
>   /Users/saurabh.mimani/work/codes/local/local_web_backend/config/application.rb:14:in
>   `block (2 levels) in <class:Application>'
>   /Users/saurabh.mimani/work/codes/local/local_web_backend/config/application.rb:13:in`
>   glob'
>   /Users/saurabh.mimani/work/codes/local/local_web_backend/config/application.rb:13:in
>   `block in '

It works fine when I replace `class EntityAttribute < Spree::Base` with 
`class EntityAttribute < ActiveRecord::Base` like this:

```
module Spree
  class EntityAttribute < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    ...
```

I also get the error when I change the module scope like following:

```
module Spree123
  class EntityAttribute < Spree::Base
    ...
    ...
```

I have also searched in the whole code, there is no other class with name: `EntityAttribute`

What can be reason of this error and how to make it working.

Comment: "superclass mismatch for class" may be you are already define the class EntityAttribute anywhere or any gem which is inherit from any other now it is again inherit  it from Spree...it occurs due to this

Comment: @RajarshiDas I thought so, I grepped it, It is nowhere and here it is inside module scope as well.